# Todos podem ver meus projetos no Github?

Tags: github

Saudações pessoal estou iniciando ai com os conceitos de GitHub e gostaria de saber quando coloco meu projeto la ele fica acessível para todas as pessoas com a opção de download.

Caso sim:
     Existe uma forma para remover essa opção de download?

Caso não: Era só isso mesmo que gostaria de saber galera, agradeço.

Comment: Existe a forma paga do GitHub que é um comportamento privado aonde só você e quem tem permissão dada por você pode utilizar. Tem https://bitbucket.org/ que é na mesma simbologia e pode ter projetos privados vai com ele!

Comment: Apesar da pergunta ser excelente e a resposta também, eu não a considero como sendo algo do escopo, não é um problema de como usar o comando `git`, não é uma duvida sobre arquivos como `.gitignore` e nem uma duvida de como usar programas como GithubDesktop, é uma duvida sobre um plano comercial sendo gratuito ou não, o que não me parece no escopo, admito que gerou uma boa resposta, mas ainda sim ela irá atrair muitas respostas promocionais e opinativas como A é melhor B. Acho que a resposta atual poderia até virar um wiki de comunidade no máximo.

Comment: Acho q vc exagerou pois toda informação referente ao assunto ou relacionado é bem vind ate pq estamos aqui para dividir conhecimentos com a ccomunidade. Mas agradeço

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Depende, você pode ter projetos privados e impedir que outras pessoas o acessem. Caso use o plano gratuito, não terá como impedir que vejam seu fonte ou que façam download dele.

O GitHub tem estas duas opções

1. **Projetos públicos**: qualquer um pode ver, forkar e baixar o código fonte.
2. **Projetos privados**: apenas os usuários que você liberar terão acesso ao código.

Projetos privados só estão disponíveis em planos pagos, que variam [entre 7 e 21 dólares ao mês](https://github.com/pricing) na data desta resposta.

Você ainda pode conseguir uma conta com repositórios privados ilimitados enquanto for estudante com o [GitHub Student Developer Pack](https://education.github.com/pack).

Existem algumas alternativas no mercado, a mais conhecida é o [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org) da Atlassian. Ele tem basicamente as mesmas funções do GitHub, porém, você pode criar projetos privados no plano gratuito, desde que o mesmo não tenha mais de 5 usuários.

Tem também o [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-com/) que você pode ter projetos **privados** ilimitados e também **não tem limite de usuários**.

---

Não vou dar muito mais detalhes sobre as ferramentas porque não convém, além de que esta é uma pergunta voltada a uma dúvida sobre o GitHub.

Comment: Vou procurar conhecer o bitbucket pq de momento é manter o projeto privado rs

Comment: Agradeço pela maravilhosa resposta cara

Answer (score 4):

Olá, projetos do github como nosso amigo explicou acima só é liberado repositórios públicos para contas free. Caso você não tenha interesse em adquirir um plano privado, tenho como sugestão explorar a ferramenta gitlab (https://about.gitlab.com/), que integra com o git normalmente e você consegue criar um projeto privado, a diferença é o limite de espaço se eu não me engano, porém, mesmo assim, é bem mais vantajoso, vale a pena conhecer a ferramenta!

Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 1):

Como o github é uma comunidade criada voltada para o publico open source por padrão a conta gratuita deixa seu projeto visível para todos que tem acesso ao site, mas para ter sua conta privada você tem que contratar um plano pago dentro do site.