# Diferenças e vantagens entre GitHub e GitLab

Tags: github, gitlab

Hoje tomei consciência sobre o GitLab, vi que muitas empresas de peso, como NASA e SpaceX, utilizam-no. Gostaria de saber quais são as diferenças dele com o GitHub, principais vantagens e desvantagens em usar ele, se vale a pena usar ele em conjunto com o GitHub, ou apenas escolher e usar apenas um dos dois, etc.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51917/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156311/101

Comment: vou dar uma olhada aqui, obrigado.

Comment: As outras respostas comparam o serviços web do GitHub e GitLab. Porém essa não é a comparação mais correta dada a pergunta, porque a Nasa e a SpaceX, entre outras, usam os serviços auto-hospedado em seus servidores próprios.
A comparação mais correta seria Gitlab Self-Hosted vs Github Enterprise, em inglês: https://www.slant.co/versus/4860/4863/~gitlab_vs_github-enterprise https://usersnap.com/blog/gitlab-github/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Uma comparação básica pode ser encontrada nesta [página](https://usersnap.com/blog/gitlab-github/) e foi traduzida livremente para cá:

**Data de lançamento:**

- GitLab: Setembro de 2011
- GitHub: Abril de 2008

Ambos estão no mercado a um tempo bastante considerável e são confiáveis.

**Preço:**

- GitLab: permite a criação de inúmeros repositórios públicos e privados gratuitamente, assim como inúmeros colaboradores;
- GitHub: permite a criação de inúmeros repositórios públicos e privados gratuitamente (Os repositórios privados gratuitos para o Github entraram em vigor em 07/01/2019);

Se deseja utilizar o serviço sem expor o código fonte, utilize os repositórios privados do GitLab. Se deseja expor o código, pode ser tanto GitLab quanto GitHub.

**Ferramentas de revisão de código:**

- GitLab: possui;
- GitHub: possui;

Não ficou claro no site o que foi considerado como ferramentas de revisão de código, mas diz que ambos possuem.

**Suporte a Wiki:**

- GitLab: possui;
- GitHub: possui;

Em ambas as plataformas é possível criar Wikis para o repositório de forma gratuita.

**Rastreamento de erros:**

- GitLab: possui;
- GitHub: possui;

Ambas as plataformas possuem sistemas de controle de *issues* para gerenciamento de erros e *bugs*.

**Branchs privadas:**

- GitLab: permite a criação de branchs privadas gratuitamente;
- GitHub: permite a criação de branchs privadas apenas nos planos pagos;

**Sistema de CI/CD:**

- GitLab: possui ferramenta gratuita nativa para CI/CD (Gitlab-CI-CD);
- GitHub: depende de ferramentas de terceiros (costuma ser Travis-CI);

Embora o GitHub funcione muito bem com o Travis-CI, o Gitlab possui um sistema nativo, então não precisa depender de terceiros.

**Popularidade:**

- GitLab: 100.000+ projetos;
- GitHub: 35.000.000+ projetos;

Tais dados provavelmente estão bem desatualizados, mas com certeza o número de projetos no GitHub supera em muito do GitLab. Se o seu projeto for OpenSource e espera ter contribuição da comunidade, com certeza o GitHub é mais indicado. Se não espera que a comunidade naturalmente contribua, o GitLab serve.

---

A interface gráfica do GitLab conta bastante. Ela é mais agradável de se usar que a interface do GitHub, embora isso seja uma opinião particular e não implica em dizer que a interface do GitHub é ruim. Outros pontos que podem afetar a escolha são as integrações com outras ferramentas de terceiros além da de CI/CD. O GitHub funciona muito bem com as principais ferramentas no mercado, enquanto o suporte para o GitLab é bem mais limitado.

Comment: Muito obrigado Anderson, me ajudou muito :D

Comment: A questão de repositórios privados gratuitos influenciou muito na escolha, apesar de ter muita coisa que deixo aberta no github existem sempre alguns projetos pessoais que preciso deixar privador e coloco agora no gitlab.

Comment: Eu acho que é digno mencionar que o GitHub tem uma pegada muito mais próxima de uma rede social do que o GitLab...

Comment: Muito boa explicação. Recentemente o o github recebeu planos gratuitos para times [veja aqui](https://github.blog/2020-04-14-github-is-now-free-for-teams)

Answer (score 13):

Resposta para complementar as demais que já respondem bem.

GitHub é da Microsoft. Como a compra é recente ainda não sabemos o que pode acontecer. Não deve mudar nada para projetos *open source*, e para projetos privados, se mudar, é ter contas gratuitas como já ocorre no VSTS, inclusive usando Git. Fora isso deverá ter mais integração, opcional, com outros serviços Microsoft, sem deixar de lado tudo o que existe de outros produtos, mesmo concorrentes. É bom lembrar que a Microsoft tem parcerias com seus concorrentes, como a Canonical e a Amazon, Apple (acho que ainda é uma importante acionista, poucos sabem disso, foi ela que salvou a Apple de quebrar nos anos 90), só para citar alguns, se olhar bem ela tem parcerias com todo mundo, nem tem como não ter, essas empresas dependem umas das outras.

Eu disse tudo isto para indicar que ele tem futuro próspero em melhorias e em sustentabilidade. Para quem não sabe, o GitHub era extremamente deficitário e nada indicava que poderia reverter isso.

O GitLab deve sofrer do mesmo problema que o GitHub. Se o GitHub era insustentável sendo o absurdo sucesso que era, imagina o GitLab que oferece quase tudo gratuitamente. Ou quebram ou serão comprados por um gigante da indústria (e pode ser alguém que já invade sua privacidade o tempo todo). Leve isso em consideração quando for usar um ou outro. Claro é menos arriscado se usar *on-premisse*, mas terá que cuidar da infra por conta própria. Além disso se acontecer algo errado adiantará pouco processar uma empresa tão pequena, a Microsoft tem muito mais em jogo e precisa ser muito mais responsável.

Hoje repositórios privados saem mais barato no GitLab, mas algo me diz que issto mudará, pelo menos para pequenos projetos, ou seja o GitHub tende a ser grátis sob certas condições. Só minha opinião, nenhuma informação privilegiada. [E [de fato isso já aconteceu](https://github.com/pricing).]

Acredito que o GitHub começará ter melhores integrações, já tem hoje, mas não nativo. [Já aconteceu e acontecerá mais.]

O tempo dirá o que acontecerá. Só garanto que não será o cataclismo que estão prevendo. [Não aconteceu o que as pessoas falaram que ia acontecer.]

O fato de uma determinada empresa usar não quer dizer muita coisa, inclusive porque ela pode usar outras tecnologias, pode fazer coisas que você nem sabe, aquilo pode ser absolutamente secundário, e pode atender a demanda deles, mas não a sua. Ao contrário da crença popular, se uma empresa grande usa bem, tem uma chance razoável de não ser bom para você. Pode ser legal, mas pode ser um canhão pra matar passarinho.

E antes que eu me esqueça, o GitLab roda dentro da estrutura da Microsoft :D

[image: ISP do GitLab é o Azure]

Eu vi que eles estão mudando pra Google. Ou seja, estão tomando decisões de engenharia por causa de marketing, para se afastar de um concorrente (mesmo eles terem disto que o processo começou (semanas) antes, o processo de compra do GitHub também, e essas coisas não ficam em segredo). E entre Google e Microsoft, quem é mais *evil* **hoje**? Pensa bem! Dizem que pelo menos a Google não os comprou. Será que não é um primeiro passo? A Google pagou, e muito, para eles irem pra lá. Você acredita que é sem motivo? GitLab é legal, mas eu não entendo porque confiar mais neles do que no GitHub.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pelas observações Maniero. Como sempre, muito útil.

Comment: Esse print foi ótimo! Muito bem lembrado, que mesmo a MicroSoft não tendo comprado o GitLab, ele roda nela

Answer (score 6):

O GitHub e o GitLab, apesar do nome, são serviços diferentes.

**GitHub**

É basicamente, até o momento, um serviço de armazenamento de repositórios Git, com algumas features do tipo: [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/) (não é uma feature nativa do Git), [Issues](https://help.github.com/articles/about-issues/), [fork](https://help.github.com/articles/about-forks/), ...

**GitLab**

Além do serviços que o GitHub oferece, implementadas pela GitLab, ou seja não é uma cópia; tem também serviço de [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration), [CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery), etc.. 
Veja toda a relação em nesta [lista de features do GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/features/)

Se você contrata o GitHub, terá que usar uma outra ferramenta para CI, por exemplo o [AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com/) ou [Jenkis](https://jenkins.io/); outra para CD, por exemplo o [Octopus](https://octopus.com/). Eu compararia o GitLab mais com os serviços da [Atlassian](https://br.atlassian.com/) e com o [VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/), que tem diversas ferramentas integradas para cobrir o pipeline inteiro de desenvolvimento de software.

Ou seja, IMHO, se você quer uma solução completa para desenvolvimento de software, analisar o GitLab, Atlassian ou VSTS é melhor. Se você vai desenvolver um software Open Source, o GitHub dá mais visibilidade, a comunidade é maior. Mas tudo vai depender das features que você quer utilizar.

Answer (score 2):

**GitHub** é o maior e mais popular serviço de armazenamento de repositórios GIT. É também mais antigo que o **GitLab** e talvez por isso seja tão popular. Se vocẽ quer apenas hospedar seu código, a desvantagem do GitHub é o preço: ao contrário do GitLab, você não conta com a opção de repositórios privados na versão *free*.

Caso você queira opções mais voltadas a *devops*, o **GitHub** possui um *marketplace* bem recheado e com mais opções que o **GitLab**, este por sua vez já traz uma série de ferramentas que exigem pouquíssima ou nenhuma configuração.

Eu hoje utilizo o GitLab mais pelo fato de poder usar repositórios privados mas isso vai da sua necessidade.

Answer (score 1):

Na forma que você vai trabalhar não vai mudar em nada, os dois são serviços que oferecem soluções para utilizar o git.

A grande diferença vai estar em qual é o seu propósito, se você estiver desenvolvendo algo OpenSource, talvez seja interessante você optar pelo Github, afinal não dá para negar que a **comunidade lá é muito mais ativa** do que nos outros serviços.

Já se você pensa em usar para algum uso mais privado, o Gitlab pode ser uma boa opção, por oferecer recursos de **repositórios privados e número de usuários ilimitados** até mesmo no seu plano gratuito